# Why do all Dash components have borders when clicked?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm following a simple tutorial to build a stock price dashboard in Plotly Dash. When the app is running on localhost, every Component gets a border when hovered or clicked. See the GIF below.

[image: borders on Dash components]

Is this due to a setting somewhere? It's very annoying, and it seems to happen in most of the Dash apps I've been making.

The code for the app is here:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


app = dash.Dash(title="Stock Dashboard")

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Stock Ticker Dashboard"),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.H4("Enter stock symbols:"),
                dcc.Input(
                    id = 'stock_picker',
                    value = 'AAPL',
                    style = dict(
                        fontSize = 24,
                        width = '100%',
                        marginRight = '15px',
                        padding = '10px 5px',
                        borderRadius = '4px'
                    )
                ),
            ],
            style = dict(
                display = 'inline-block',
                verticalAlign = 'middle',
                marginRight = '20px',
                width = '40%'
            )
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.H4("Choose a date range:"),
                dcc.DatePickerRange(
                    id = 'date_picker',
                    min_date_allowed = datetime(2010, 1, 1),
                    max_date_allowed = datetime.today(),
                    start_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=365),
                    end_date = datetime.today(),
                ),
            ],
            style = dict(
                display = 'inline-block',
                verticalAlign = 'middle',
                marginLeft = '20px'
            )
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Button(
                    id = 'submit_button',
                    n_clicks = 0,
                    children = "Submit",
                    style = dict(
                        fontSize = 24,
                        marginLeft = '30px'
                    )
                )
            ],
            style = dict(
                display = 'inline-block',
                verticalAlign = 'bottom'
            )
        ),
        html.Div(
            [
                dcc.Graph(
                    id = 'stock_graph',
                    figure = dict(
                        data = [{'x': [1,2], 'y': [3,1]}],
                        layout = go.Layout(
                            xaxis = dict(
                                title = dict(
                                    text = "Date",
                                ),
                            ),
                            yaxis = dict(
                                title = dict(
                                    text = "Closing Price / [$]",
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    style = dict(
                        height = '600px'
                    )
                )
            ],
            style = dict(
                height = '600px'
            )
        )
    ],
    style = dict()
)

@app.callback(
    Output('stock_graph', 'figure'),
    [Input('submit_button', 'n_clicks')],
    [
        State('stock_picker', 'value'),
        State('date_picker', 'start_date'),
        State('date_picker', 'end_date')
    ],
)
def update_graph(n_clicks, stock_ticker, start_date, end_date):
    start = datetime.strptime(start_date[:10], '%Y-%M-%d')
    end = datetime.strptime(end_date[:10], '%Y-%M-%d')

    print(f"Getting stock prices for: {stock_ticker}, [{start} - {end}]")
    df = web.DataReader(stock_ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)

    fig = dict(
        data = [go.Scatter(
            x = df.index,
            y = df['Close'],
            mode = 'lines'
        )],
        layout = dict(
            title = stock_ticker,
            yaxis = dict(
                title = 'Closing Price / [$]'
            )
        )
    )

    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Edited to add the version numbers for some of the modules (please let me know if I should include others):

```
pandas==1.1.1
pandas-datareader==0.9.0
dash-core-components==1.10.2
dash-html-components==1.0.3
dash-renderer==1.6.0
dash-table==4.9.0
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Compress==1.5.0
```

Comment: I believe it's in the style sheet you're using. It looks like each section is a <div> tag so look there.

Comment: Do you have any .css files in your assets folder?

Comment: @hrokr - the only stylesheets being used are imported by `Dash` on its own. However, inspecting the `divs` in the browser doesn't show any applied styles, even when the colored border shows up.

Comment: @emher - I'm not explicitly importing any assets or css for this app. Do you know where `Dash` keeps its own static files for styles?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: This is not happening for me when I run your code. I suspect it's coming from your IDE, or browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a dingus. It was from my React Developer Tools addon (Firefox 79.0). Not sure why that setting got turned on, but there you go. :facepalm: